# What does that mean in Python time.time() documentation?

Tags: python, time

Documentation says-"While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls."
in https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time

Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: If a user or some program changes time or date of the computer's clock, the returned value may decrease because it is just calculated from the time and date of the system.

Comment: see also [time.monotonic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) for comparison